# Creating measure to return total for "context" month transactions only

Tags: powerbi, dax

Hope you can help.. I've tried a few different things and can't get this one to work..

So I have a transactions table linked to a dates table...

I'm trying to work out the "Current month spend" .. where the current month would be the month should be the most recent month

So for FY23,  Current month= 5 (May)

For FY22 ,  Current month= 6 (June)

My "Current Month SPend" calculation is:

Current month spend =
VAR FY = SELECTEDVALUE(Dates[FY])
RETURN
CALCULATE([ABS Amount], FILTER(Dates, Dates[MonthOfYear]=[LASTMONTH] && Dates[FY]=FY))

The problem is this also returns the values for transactions in April, because for some categories April is the most recent transaction..

For those categories where a transaction has not occurred in the "context" month, then they should show as 0.

If I change the above formula for Current month spend and hard code [LASTMONTH] to be 5  - it works fine!  But obviously that's not a permanent fix.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Asha